# Metamask: Will imported account be lost after seed restoration?

Tags: metamask, hd-wallets

Since metamask is a HD wallet, in case of storing some imported accounts in my wallet and after wallet restoration, metamask will only be able to restore derived pairs with the exception of imported ones. In other words, I will not be able to restore imported accounts.

Can someone confirm?

Comment: This is purely a Metamask question unrelated to ethereum. You should ask it on Metamask forum. It will likely be closed.

Comment: Is metamask not part of the ethereum OS ecosystem?

Comment: Yeah you're right, wallet questions are allowed (I just reread the rules).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you restore your Metamask wallet, your imported accounts (such as hardware wallet) will not be restored. You will have to link them again on Metamask.